# DataRange not working in GraphPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to create a a GUI that uses the `GraphPlot` function to automatically generate graph vertices. I am using the `VertexCoordinateRules` option to designate that I want some of the vertices to be at certain positions.

Because of this, I want to ensure that all the vertices are between 0 and 1 on both the x and y axes. From the documentation, it seems that the DataRange option should be able to do this, but it isn't working. Any ideas on how I can constrain all vertices to be between 0 and 1?

`GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4, 
  4 -> 5, 5 -> 6}, VertexCoordinateRules -> {3 -> {.9, .9}, 1 -> {.1, .2}}, DataRange->{{0,1},{0,1}}][[1,2,2]]`

(The [[1,2,2]] shows the actual coordinates of the vertices, rather than just the graph itself)

Comment: I fiddled with this for about an hour, adding/removing options and components, looking at internal form of the result, etc. I had same result. I did not try other graph types (e.g. tree), but for your simple graph type, `DataRange` does not seem to do what is implied in the docs (for that matter, it doesn't seem to do *anything*). I'd suggest waiting a little to see if some of the plot heavies here have an idea, then reporting it to WRI support.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yeah it seems like they forgot to actually implement the DataRange function for graph plots

Comment: Any news on that. In Version 11.0: Still nothing happens.